# Reverse engineering a firmware: Compresssion or Encryption ? And how to extract data?

Tags: iot, reverse-engineering

I'm new to IoT reverse engineering but I have some basic knowledge. This time I wanted to step up the game a bit. So, I extracted a firmware from an old camera nand chip. The camera use Ambarella SoC.

Here is what I did so far:

**Hexdump:**

```
00000000  c1 00 00 ea 61 31 32 00  00 00 00 00 66 a0 33 01  |....a12.....f.3.|
00000010  a8 61 00 00 74 09 27 08  1d 11 e5 14 8b 8e 98 40  |.a..t.'........@|
00000020  de 70 44 70 10 27 00 00  31 17 00 01 40 00 01 01  |.pDp.'..1...@...|
00000030  08 00 02 01 00 00 03 01  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  |............@...|
00000040  2d 00 02 00 26 00 00 00  0a                       |-...&....|
00000049
```

**Entropy:**

[Entropy screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpX8q.png)

**Binwalk:**

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
207281        0x329B1         Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 5612
256948        0x3EBB4         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
260397        0x3F92D         Copyright string: "Copyright (C) 2004-2014"
1087744       0x109900        Flattened device tree, size: 14761 bytes, version: 17
1222912       0x12A900        Flattened device tree, size: 14761 bytes, version: 17
1757184       0x1AD000        Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
1773643       0x1B104B        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
10905580      0xA667EC        SHA256 hash constants, little endian
11879281      0xB54371        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 5384
12304642      0xBBC102        Linux kernel version 3.10.7
12311644      0xBBDC5C        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
12387788      0xBD05CC        DES SP2, little endian
12388812      0xBD09CC        DES SP1, little endian
12412100      0xBD64C4        LZO compressed data
12853728      0xC421E0        Unix path: /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/-pipeline_release_2.2_FWLPD-6173/amba-linux-sdk/ambarella/kernel/linux-3.10/init/main.c
12856613      0xC42D25        Unix path: /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/-pipeline_release_2.2_FWLPD-6173/amba-linux-sdk/ambarella/kernel/linux-3.10/init/initramfs.c
**[...]**
13536452      0xCE8CC4        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev", file name length: "0x00000004", file size: "0x00000000"
13536568      0xCE8D38        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev/console", file name length: "0x0000000C", file size: "0x00000000"
13536692      0xCE8DB4        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "root", file name length: "0x00000005", file size: "0x00000000"
13536808      0xCE8E28        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
13567488      0xCF0600        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
17977344      0x1125000       UBI erase count header, version: 1, EC: 0x1, VID header offset: 0x800, data offset: 0x1000
```

By executing `binwalk -Mre`, I got those empty folders and one empty file:
[Binwalk extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT4hO.png)

Also, by executing strings command, I saw lot of clear text but I don't know if this a binary or a mix of lot things...

My question is how to extract something useful from this data. Is there anything that should be done before to have like binaries or files... ?

Thanks in advance !